# Apply style to child component when parent is hovered

Tags: reactjs

I have a `li` tag that has a child `label` with text. This child label has styling so when it is hovered it does an animation. I wanted to trigger this animation when the parent (`li`) is hovered. How can I do this?

Additionally, when I click the child (label) tag, the onClick event of the `li` is not triggered. What can I do to propagate the click over the child to the parent?

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('1')
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const target = e.target
    setActiveTab(target.id)
  }

  return (
    <Styled.Tabs>
      <Styled.TabList>
        {data.map(({ id, job, institution, date, summary }) => {
          return (
            <Styled.TabItem
              key={id}
              id={id.toString()}
              onClick={handleClick}
              className={activeTab === id.toString() ? 'active' : ''}
            >
              <Styled.HoverEffectText>{job}</Styled.HoverEffectText>
            </Styled.TabItem>
          )
        })}
      </Styled.TabList>
```

I am using `styled-components`. The behaviour I am getting is that I hovering over `HoverEffectText` (the label) triggers its hovering properties, and only hovering outside of it can I activate the `li` tab or trigger `li` onHover styling.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please post some code sample / stackblitz link so that we can suggest you a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create this hover effect using css like this.

```
 .parent:hover .child {
    //hover stlyes...
}
```

and as for the parent element handling the event, I'm pretty sure you would just want to put the onClick event in the parent element.